# Rails joins query with multiple conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join, rails-activerecord

I am trying query 2 tables, Credentials and Integrations.

I want to retrieve every credential record `WHERE user_id == current_user.id`. I also want to retrieve every integration record `WHERE name == "Twitter"`.

The query directly below runs and outputs `[[4, "Twitter"][3,"YouTube"]]`

```
Credential.joins(:integration).where(user_id: current_user.id).pluck(:id, :name)
```

The query directly below is supposed to run and produce `[4, "Twitter"]` but instead it produces an error.

```
Credential.joins(:integration).where(user_id: current_user.id).where(integration: {name: 'Twitter'}).pluck(:id, :name)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "integration"
LINE 1: ...ration_id" WHERE "credentials"."user_id" = $1 AND "integrati...
```

Ultimately, I am trying to whitelist what integrations I use in the rest of the code. Rails rejects the query if I use a plural in the joins argument `.joins(:integrations)` .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the plural version in your `where` clause.

```
where(integrations: {..})

Credential.joins(:integration)
  .where(user_id: current_user.id)
  .where(integrations: {name: 'Twitter'})
  .pluck(:id, :name)
```